# Are questions that ask about interactions of open source licenses of specific products on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1973/edting-jasper-server-community-edition-code-and-distribute was put on hold as off-topic because it "asks for support for a specific product". Relevant meta-discussions are

- [Are questions about the licences of popular open source projects on-topic here?](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/491/are-questions-about-the-licences-of-popular-open-source-projects-on-topic-here) seems most closely related; a question about how the license of a specific open source product applies to that license. There is at the time I write this no answer with over 0 net votes on that question, so I don't think we can make up much in the way of consensus from that question.
- [Are technical questions about specific software that happens to be open source on-topic?](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150/are-questions-about-specific-software-on-topic) where the subject of the question is how to use the specific software (which, unrelatedly, happens to be open source). The answer is no, technical support for an open source product is off topic here.
- [Do we want to allow specific questions?](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161/do-we-want-to-allow-specific-questions) A question on specialized questions. The outcome was that questions applicable to a narrow group are on topic.

Does this question "ask for support for a specific open source product" as examplified in the second meta discussion? More importantly, is it on topic?

Answer (score 6):

This question is not asking for support of a specific open source product, and is on topic.

This site should be a site where you can ask questions if you run in to a question about open source, and get a good answer.

This question is about a person who is unsure how the open source license he received for some software works. They have a specific question about a specific license of a product. That's a beautiful, near perfect fit for our Q&A format. It's what this site should be about.

If we reject questions like these because they are too specialized, we close of the opportunity for people to ask questions about specific license interactions, and severely limit our usefulness - possibly even our reason we're here.

Not everyone is interested in abstracts and general situations. Some people just want to know whether they can do licensing thing X when they have a product with open source license Y. Those people should receive a proper answer here.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree here. We can't only accept 'generic' questions: we'll just push ourselves into a royal mess. About that specific question though, I personally would've closed that as 'Unclear what you're asking'.

Answer (score 1):

*raises hand and waves it in the air*

I put this question on hold as off-topic because it seemed to me as though it was specifically asking a question about Jasper Server Community Edition, and whether a certain thing could be done with it.

Now maybe that's a problem, or maybe it's not. Up to you lot to decide that. My humble opinion is that it would be better phrased more generally - for *a generic AGPL-licensed project* rather than *Jasper Server*.

Comment: I don't think we should genericize (this is a word now) such questions. For us freetards it might be easy to see how the generalized answer applies to the specific question, but the asker isn't - at least that we have any indication of - interested in the general case. The asker is interested in the particular case of how the licensing of Jasper Server interacts with distribution of an end product. We should respect that distinction and answer the question that is asked. Not the question we believe they should be asking. Referring in that answer to a more general answer is fine though.

Answer (score 1):

I voted to close it as unclear, not off-topic. While generic questions (as in, specific licenses, but not specific products) are more reusable than specific questions, if it is edited to be given enough clarity I think it should be reopened. But while it's being edited it could also be made generic too.